# Share files over hosted network

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, file-transfer

I have a laptop device and a desktop device with a `WLAN Adapter`, i set up a hotspot on my laptop with admin instance of command prompt with `netsh wlan start hostednetwork`. I have my PC connected to that network. I opened File Explorer on the PC  and opened the `Network folder` where i located the laptop device hostname. I tried to open that network location to access some public folder called `repos` but couldn't. Windows Explorer is asking for credentials i did not even configure.
Attached is a screenshot of the message. I read from `Microsoft Official website` that `HomeGroup` has been discontinued. So how do i create a local area network to be able to share files across my PC and laptop?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing to set up – file sharing via SMB just uses the exact same credentials as your Windows login (on the target "server" system, of course). The only difference is that it will *not* accept a blank password.

("HomeGroup" is not needed for SMB to work; it was only a system to automatically create a shared credential and keep it synchronized across all PCs that were members of the homegroup.)

Comment: Same Windows login as target server system?I guess this is my default password and username on target machine

Comment: Worked like a charm , am now able to access files and folders in the repos folder